# Migrating an Ubuntu mirror made with `apt-mirror`

Tags: mirrors, apt-mirror

We have one office with broadband and another one with dialup. My goal is to create a local Ubuntu mirror on the second office.

I have used `apt-mirror` on my local machine, and it downloaded about 130GB of packages. How do I transfer these files to another computer to create a local mirror? Do I just copy the folders with the `.deb` files to the new machine? Do I need to edit config files or perform another action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have formatted an external drive with ext filesystem and just set the download point there.  Just the folder with the deb files will not be enough.  Look at your apt-mirror config.  Wherever the config points for the "root" is where you need to base your recursive copy.